# How do I make sure that Antlr4 gets credit for my new language

Tags: antlr, licensing

I just developed a new language using that Antlr4 libraries. I was reading the license and I noticed that if I do develop a product using Antlr, I need to give the credit to the Antlr contributors (Particularly Terrance Parr). I want to make sure that I do everything correctly and on the up and up, so I'm not sure where to put the credit, in my product.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Typcially you would mention 3rd party libraries in a readme file or a contributors file. Often used is also the "about" information all applications have. Yet another possibility is the documentation, but that must be accessible in public. You don't need to add a note everywhere, just one place is enough.